# Add dynamic column to table at runtime using Telerik reporting tool

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, telerik-reporting

I want to add to the table at the run time new columns using Telerik reporting tool I'm using stored procedures as SQL data source this my code

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Validate_years]
    @yearsselected nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     IF 1 = 0 
     BEGIN
         SET FMTONLY OFF
     END

     DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT OutputVar_Name, UnitName '
 
     SELECT @sql += ',' + QUOTENAME(c.name)
     FROM sys.columns AS c
     INNER JOIN [ICAM_DB].[dbo].[Years_Tbl] AS b ON c.name = CONVERT(sysname, Year)
     WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[ICAM_DB].[dbo].[OutputStreamDataSetup_Tbl]') and  CONVERT(sysname, Year)=@yearsselected;;
  
SET @sql += N' FROM [ICAM_DB].[dbo].[OutputStreamDataSetup_Tbl] WHERE ResultVariable_ID in (1016,1014,1015)';
set @yearsselected=+  N' FROM [ICAM_DB].[dbo].[Years_Tbl] WHERE Year  IN (@OutputStreamDataSetup_Tbl_Year )';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;

END
```

this is the output

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |unitname|  |OutputVar_Name|         | 2010| | 2011| | 2020| | 2050 | 

------------------------------------------------------------------------
 stream1          test                 122    221      21       170
 stream2          test                 134    222      25       256
 stream3          test                 155    243      50       568
 stream4          test                 123    144      63       430
........................................................................
```

and from the year table, all the year columns generated dynamically I want the report to generate it dynamically too
**update **
the two tables that I retrieve the data from
table A

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|id| |name|           | 2010| | 2011| | 2012| | 2013| ...| 2060|

----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   stream1            122    221      123   111
2   stream2            134    222      234   222
3   stream3            155    243      234   333
4   stream4            123    144      345   444
...................................................................
```

table B this's dynamic

```
--------------------
|yearsid| |years|          
--------------------
1        2010           
2        2011            
3        2020            
4        2050            
....................
```

Comment: The SQL code above is product specific. Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps MS SQL Server?)

Comment: i'm using Microsoft SQL management studio 2019

Comment: There is no SSMS 2019 @ReemElshenawy, the latest version is 18.9.2. Do you mean SQL Server 2019?

Comment: yes sql server 2019 ssms 18.9.2

Answer (score 1):

Just select the Year on rows, and let the front-end worry about pivoting the results.  eg

```
SELECT OutputVar_Name, UnitName, Year
FROM [ICAM_DB].[dbo].[OutputStreamDataSetup_Tbl] 
WHERE ResultVariable_ID in (1016,1014,1015)
and Year  IN ( select cast(value as int) from string_split(@OutputStreamDataSetup_Tbl_Year,',') )
```

Comment: hi David it's not all the data in one table it's two tabled years tbl and outputstreamsDataSetup Tbl and they don't have any relation

Comment: Whatever.  Just write a query that returns a fixed set of columns and a variable number of rows.  That's how SQL works best.  Trying to put variable data on columns in SQL is a complex hack.  Then display the data however you want at the front-end.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean is to pivot and unpivot the tables I tried this it worked but what I asked is how to change these values at the run time in the Telerik reporting tool I want to make the column change dynamically, so if you please can you show me an example?

Comment: That's a Telerik question, and I don't know anything about that tool.  But you're looking for some UI element like an SSRS Tablix, a Power BI Matrix, or an Excel Pivot Table.  Or you can transform the data in code if this is a custom applicaiton.